# \Function adds () on the second letter in algorithmic

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

How can I get rid of the () on the second letter of the Function statement?
The code:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\begin{algorithmic}
\Function Signature(df)
\If {Condition 1}
    \State a
    \State b
    \State c
    \State d
    \State e
\EndIf
\EndFunction
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

Image:
[image: Image of the Algorithm]

Comment: `\Functiosn{Signature}{df}`…

Answer (score 2):

The command `\Function` takes two arguments, the first being the function name and the second its parameters. Since you didn't put curly brackets, the S from signature is interpreted as the function name and the i as its argument. Just use

```
\Function {Signature}{df}
```

instead. For a function with multiple arguments, use `\Function {Signature}{df, <second argument>, ...}`.

Comment: Thank You. I should read the package help more.

Answer (score 1):

From the `algorithmicx` documentation:

[image]

[image]

As you see, `\Function` wants two braced arguments, but you don't have braces, so by general TeX rule `S` is taken as the first and `i` as the second.

Solution:

```
\Function{Signature}{df}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I should read the package more.